# echo the exact command-line passed to a command with visible quotes

Tags: bash, quoting

So I can quite happily build up a command line into a bash array, and then execute it with quotes and get each argument nicely quoted:

```
declare -a cmd_args
cmd_args=("-p" "dir path/with spaces")
mkdir "${cmd_args[@]}"
echo dir*/*
```

But how can I get this echoed to the screen in a way that makes sense - i.e. showing the user a command that they could then type, or that I could keep in a log file for future reference? All these look (basically) the same:

```
echo runnimg mkdir with arguments ${cmd_args[@]}
echo runnimg mkdir with arguments "${cmd_args[@]}"
echo "runnimg mkdir with arguments '${cmd_args[@]}'"
echo "runnimg mkdir with arguments '${cmd_args[*]}'"

==> runnimg mkdir with arguments '-p dir path/with spaces'
```

Which is clearly the wrong command. This is not showing the user a command that they could then type, or that I could keep in a log file and reproduce at a future date. I want to see:

```
runnimg mkdir with arguments '"-p" "dir path/with spaces"'
```

I thought about using `cat<<EOF`:

```
cat<<EOF 
"${cmd_args[@]}" 
EOF
```

but in fact, that generates one big quote around the whole argument list! What gives here? How could this *ever* be my intent? If it was, then I have `"${cmd_args[*]}"`.

So that is the challenge. Print the command in a way that the user can say, "yes, that is the correct command".

Sorry to those saying "%p\n", but while that might be OK for a log file, but still a pain to go back and format it "unabiguously" in order to retest the command, it isn't really good enough for the interactive "this is the command feedback to the user".

Perhaps there is an answer already, but if so it is swamped by all the "always quote your arguments" type answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I_want_a_log_of_my_script.27s_actions):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

trap 'printf RUNNING:\ %s\\n "$BASH_COMMAND" >&2' DEBUG

foo () {
    printf '%s\n' "$@" > /dev/null
}

foo bar baz

foo 'qux bazinga' '1 2' 3 '4 5'

foo "I'm going home"
```

The `DEBUG` trap outputs:

```
RUNNING: foo bar baz
RUNNING: foo 'qux bazinga' '1 2' 3 '4 5'
RUNNING: foo "I'm going home"
```

Showing the quotes as they appear in the script.

The function `foo` is set to output to `/dev/null` so we can ignore its output. It's just a stand-in for whatever commands your script may actually be running.

Here is a version that puts the `trap` code in a function and calls that function to turn the trap on and off. This is useful if you only want the trap to handle certain sections of code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

dbt () {
    if [[ $1 == on ]]
    then
        trap 'printf RUNNING:\ %s\\n "$BASH_COMMAND" >&2' DEBUG
    elif [[ $1 == off ]]
    then
        trap '' DEBUG
    else
        printf '%s\n' "Invalid action: $1"
    fi
}

foo () {
    printf '%s\n' "$@" > /dev/null
}

foo bar baz

dbt on

foo 'qux bazinga' '1 2' 3 '4 5'

foo "I'm going home"

now=$(date)

dbt off

declare -a array_b

dbt on

array_b=(a b 'c d' e)
```

which outputs:

```
RUNNING: foo 'qux bazinga' '1 2' 3 '4 5'
RUNNING: foo "I'm going home"
RUNNING: now=$(date)
RUNNING: dbt off
RUNNING: array_b=(a b 'c d' e)
```

Another way to trace execution of a script is to use [`set -x`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin).

> Print a trace of simple commands, for commands, case commands, select commands, and arithmetic for commands and their arguments or associated word lists after they are expanded and before they are executed. The value of the PS4 variable is expanded and the resultant value is printed before the command and its expanded arguments.

Comment: This traps all commands that are emitted, or all internal function calls? That is better than I currently have I guess, thanks, especially as I don't tend to use functions very much. Though I would like to only worry about the "major" commands :-)

Comment: @GemTaylor: It will trap all commands that are executed, for example, all the ones in your first code block in your question. You can enable and disable the trap around sections of code you want to be output specially. I'll add an example of that to my answer. I only included the function in order to have some simple thing to demonstrate. However, functions are very useful for code organization and maintainability through reduced repetition.

Comment: I hope to play with this tomorrow. Let's see what the output if for a quote-expanded array...

Comment: @GemTaylor: The DEBUG trap is run before any processing, including variable expansion and obviously quote removal, is performed.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to print the list of arguments with each one quoted regardless if quote were appropriate:

```sh
printf '"%s" ' "${cmd_args[@]}"
```

If you want to print the list of arguments with quote or escaping only when required:

```sh
printf '%q ' "${cmd_args[@]}"
```

To do you way:

```sh
printf 'runnimg mkdir with arguments:'
printf ' %q' "${cmd_args[@]}"
```

A `dash` `ksh` POSIX shell compatible implementation:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env dash

#cmd_args=("-p" "dir path/with spaces")
# dash and POSIX shell don't have arrays
# but support setting the arguments like this:
set -- -p "dir path/with spaces"
printf 'runnimg mkdir with arguments:'
# dash built-in printf does not know about %q format,
# but system command printf does.
env printf ' %q' "$@"
echo

mkdir "$@"
```

Comment: The `'%q '` way is great because it's visually unambiguous and captures everything about the arguments in a way that can be copy-pasted into a different shell. `'"%s"'` won't work if the argument contains e.g. `"` or `$`

Comment: @thatotherguy The `%q` format will produce something that'll work pasted into bash, but not necessarily into other shells. For instance, if the string contains non-printing characters, it tends to use ANSI quoting mode (e.g. `$'\t'` for tab) -- which is visually clear, but won't work in a basic shell like dash.

Comment: Yes, the intended meaning was "%q allows the user to easily reproduce the execution by copypasting it into a second shell instance" and not "%q is useful for porting scripts between different shell implementations"

Comment: @GordonDavisson I added a `dash`/POSIX-compatible implementation

Comment: In fact I went with %q for my purposes, but the debug thing was more accurate!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `declare -p`:

```
$ cmd_args=("-p" "dir path/with spaces")
$ declare -p cmd_args
declare -a cmd_args=([0]="-p" [1]="dir path/with spaces")
```

or use the `%q` formatting directive:

```
$ printf '%q\n' "${cmd_args[@]}"
-p
dir\ path/with\ spaces
```

Comment: But this is still not showing the argument with spaces to the user with quotes? I/.e it isn't showing the user a command that they could then type, or that I could keep in a log file. Updating the question, because clearly my intent is lost.

Comment: @GemTaylor Well, `%q` won't show pretty quotes around the whole string but escape each character separately (like in Léa's second answer), but that output can directly be re-used as a shell command.